# If you are using the Documents List API and the changes feed, how does one exclude files a user has open?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-docs-api

The drive SDK has includeSubscribed for drive.changes.list. Is there an equivalent in Documents List ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no equivalent according to my current knowledge.